# Technique to know the Default scheduler in hadoop

Tags: hadoop

I have installed a multi node setup in 3 Ubuntu systems 12.04. I am using Hadoop1.2.1 in all three.Now i want to which scheduler is running by default???
How to check the default scheduler running in Hadoop1.2.1?

Answer (score 1):

Default scheduler in hadoop is `JobQueueTaskScheduler`, which is a FIFO scheduler. As a default scheduler you need to refer the property `mapred.jobtracker.taskScheduler` in [mapred-default.xml](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.1.1/mapred-default.html). If you want you can change the default scheduler to either CapacityScheduler or FairScheduler based on your requirement.

mapred-site.xml is used to override the default values inside mapred-default.xml, which can be found inside the configuration directory. You may not find mapred-default file in the configuration directory along with hadoop binary distribution(rpm,deb etc.), instead  mapred-default.xml can be found directly inside the jar file hadoop-core-1.2.1.jar.

```
hackzon:~/hadoop-1.2.1$ jar -tvf hadoop-core-1.2.1.jar  | grep mapred-default.xml
 47324 Mon Jul 22 15:12:48 IST 2013 mapred-default.xml
```

These file is used in the below mentioned hadoop source files as an argument to `addDefaultResource()` method as

```
addDefaultResource("mapred-default.xml");   // First
addDefaultResource("mapred-site.xml");   // Second
```

Initially mapred-default.xml would be loaded, then mapred-site.xml. So that properties which need to be overridden can be specified inside mapred-site.xml

```
org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.java
org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf.java
org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker.java
org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.java
org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker.java
org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobHistoryServer.java
```

Have a look at any of the source code.

Comment: Thank you very much sir. I am new to Hadoop and i am struggling like anything since January 2014. I will look in what you have said.

Comment: But sir i checked the /usr/local/hadoop/hadoop.1.2.1/conf directory i didn't get the file mapred-default.xml only..

Comment: sir in hadoop-1.1.2 its mapred-site.xml file.

Answer (score 1):

Goto your Resource Manager UI and under "Tools" click on "Configuration", or simply type the url. Replace `<resource-manager>` with your resource manager domain name.

`http://<resource-manager>:8088/conf`

Search for any settings that you want.

Answer (score 0):

After much hard work i finally got how to check the scheduler which is running in Hadoop-1.1.2. After running a word-count job i went into jobtracker web interface. There go for job history. there right side of job file one link will be there. Click on it you will get every thing like scheduler, dfs replication etc.

Also sir in hadoop-1.1.2 its mapred-site.xml file where we need to add some properties as specified in apache documentation for hadoop-1.1.2.