# changing default scheduler in hadoop 1.2.1

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

As FIFO has been default scheduler in hadoop 1.2.1, where exactly do i need to make changes to change default scheduler from FIFO to capacity or fair. I had recently checked mapred-default.xml which is present inside hadoop-core-1.2.1.jar as directed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23035057/2308683) but i didnt get where to hit and change the scheduling criteria. Please provide guidance thanking in advance

Comment: Why are you using a 2.5 year old version of Hadoop?

Comment: I am a kind of beginner in hadoop so initially i didnt knew much about it. But as most of my work (college project) is been completed on 1.2.1 itself, i am in very need of changing scheduling method for this version only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> where exactly do i need to make changes to change default scheduler from FIFO to capacity or fair

In the `mapred-site.xml`

[Fair Scheduler](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/fair_scheduler.html)

```
<property>
  <name>mapred.jobtracker.taskScheduler</name>
  <value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FairScheduler</value>
</property>
```

[Capacity Scheduler](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/capacity_scheduler.html)

```
<property>
  <name>mapred.jobtracker.taskScheduler</name>
  <value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.CapacityTaskScheduler</value>
</property>
```

Note, you may want to actually read the documentation from those links because they tell you how to set them up in detail.